# Incorrect values in array_words array 2

Tags: ruby

can you please help me with:

```
str1 = gets.chomp
start_position = 0
max = str1.length - 1
array_words = Array.new

def get_str1(str1, max, start_position, array_words)
  for x in start_position..max
    
      pom = str1[start_position]
      str1[start_position] = str1[x]
      str1[x] = pom

      puts "Inside loop: " + str1
      array_words << str1 
  end   

  puts array_words
end 

#this code returns cab cab cab as a final output due to pointers in the array array_words

#########################################################
```

Why this output returns 1,2,3,4,..10 except of 10 times values 10? basically array_new is handling pointers of variable str so it should affect the array if str value is changed.

```
def add_values(array_new, str)
  for x in 1..10
    str = x
    array_new << str
  end
  puts array_new
end
add_values(array_new, str)
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, but the function `add_values(array_words, str1)` changes the array and 10 get added each time I run the code. Is this not what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Since Integer is immutable in ruby = is reassigment operation in this case.

```
x = 3
str = x
array_new << str

x = 4
str = x
array_new << str
```

So your code doing these things:

1. Create a new Integer with a value of 3 (object_id: 7)
2. Assign this to str (points to object_id: 7)
3. Pushes it to array_new [points to object_id_7]
4. Create a new Integer with a value of 4 (object_id: 9)
5. Assign this to str (points to object_id: 9)
6. Pushes it to array_new [points to object_id_7, points_to_object_id_9]

Comment: `str = x` always reassigns `str`, regardless of whether `x` is immutable.